# i can't exit while loop without using exit(). Neither break nor return don't exit the loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, return, break, exit

```
machine = True
money = 0

def game():
    global money, machine
    while machine:
        order = input("What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino) ") # Gets order
        machine = for_maintainers(order) # if input "off" returns False. if input "report" calls game() recursively printing resources and money. if input anything else returns True.
        if not machine:
            exit()  #*** if I put here break or return when i type "off" if resources not enough, then program keeps continuing.** *
        main_menu = sufficient_resources(order) #Returns true if any resource isn't enough. If everything is enough then returns nothing.
        if main_menu:
            game()
        money_inserted = get_money(order) #asks how much quarters, dimes etc. was put. Adds them all and returns that value.
        money = enough_money(money, money_inserted, order) # Compares price and inserted money. if not enough calls game(), if enough then adds money to resources by returning money.
        make_coffee(order) #Subtracts from resources coffee, milk, water. 


game()
```

I am coding a coffee machine program. Program works fine until resources finish. To test the program i set resources 0 then i type "latte" it says there is not enough resources, that's fine but then if type "off" to exit it continues asking me insert coins(ignores or doesn't read break or return command inside loop). If i change break or return to exit(), in that case it works as i wanted, quits the program.
I am really a beginner. Please explain to me why i need to use exit() and not break or return to exit the loop.

Comment: if i type report for example program should show me resources after that it should ask me again what i want. if i don't call recursively `game` how would i achieve that?

Comment: Your example is quite unclear. you should try to generalize your question. As i understand it now, after you've handled the last input, you want the game loop to run again. Your while loop will make sure that question is asked again. You don't need to break that loop or call recursively at all when you want to repeat the cycle. You only need to break if you want to stop.

Comment: And you can use `continue` if you want to jump straight to the next iteration of the loop without finishing the current one.

Comment: The behaviour of this code will depend, in part, on how for_maintainers() is implemented. Unfortunately, we can't see that. Also, as has already been said, the recursive call to game() is going to confuse you even more than you are already

Comment: SOLVED: instead of calling `game()` after `if main_menu()`: i used `continue` statement and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the real intention for calling the `game()` function as recursion. If you don't wanna change anything, here's a work-around (not-recommended):

```py
if main_menu:
    game()
    break
```

== **The answer ends here** ==

== **Below is opinion-based** ==

Here is an assumption on what you are trying to do. If you want to reset your `money` variable, you can simply do:

```py
if main_menu:
    money = 0
    continue
```